# "Human-readable" ANTLR-generated code?

Tags: antlr

I've been learning ANTLR for a few days now. My goal in learning it was that I would be able to generate parsers and lexers, and then personally hand-translate them from Java into my target language (neither C/C++/Java/C#/Python, no tool has support for it). I chose ANTLR because from its About page: ANTLR is widely used because it's easy to understand, powerful, flexible, generates **human-readable** output[...]

In learning this tool, I decided to start with a simple lexer for a simple grammar: JSON. However, once I generated the .java file for this lexer using ANTLR4 I was caught widely off-guard. I got a huge mess of far-from-human-readable serialized code, followed by:

```
    public static final ATN _ATN =
    ATNSimulator.deserialize(_serializedATN.toCharArray());
static {
    _decisionToDFA = new DFA[_ATN.getNumberOfDecisions()];
}
```

A few Google searches were unable to provide me a way to disable this behavior.

Is there a way to disable this behavior and produce human-readable code, or am I going to have to hand-write my lexers and parsers for this target programming language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANTLR 4 uses a new algorithm for prediction. Terence Parr is currently working on a tech report describing the algorithm in detail. The human-readable output refers to the generated parsers.

ANTLR 4 lexers use a DFA recognizer for a massive speed and memory usage improvement over previous releases of ANTLR. For parsers, the `_ATN` field is a data structure used within calls to `adaptivePredict` (you'll notice lines in the generated code calling that method).

You won't be able to manually translate the generated Java code of an ANTLR 4 lexer to another programming language. You might be able to manually translate the code of a generated parser provided the grammar is strictly LL(1) (i.e. the generated code does not contain any calls to `adaptivePredict`). However, you will lose the error recovery ability that draws from information encoded in the serialized ATN.

Comment: Would it be worthwhile to look into flex/Bison, or would the generated code be equally unreadable?

Comment: I think that human readable has been declining as the version increased, which resulted in faster parsers and lexers.  In Antlr 2, even the lexer was rather legible.

Comment: @Zac My experience with flex is that the code it generates is also not very human readable.